# Add pauses to a JavaScript glitch effect

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval, visual-glitch

I have an effect that causes a canvas element to "glitch". I would like to edit the effect so that there is more pause between each glitch – as of now, the glitch pause is too short and the glitch is too close to the one before. You can see it in action here: http://naratif.jvitasek.cz/

Also, the code for the glitch is as follows:

```
function glitchElement(sourceImg, idCanvas) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById(idCanvas)
      , context = canvas.getContext('2d')
      , img = new Image()
      , w
      , h
      , offset
      , glitchInterval;

    img.src = sourceImg;
    img.onload = function() {
      init();
        window.onresize = init;
    };

    var init = function() {
        clearInterval(glitchInterval);
        canvas.width = w = window.innerWidth;
        offset = w * .1;
        canvas.height = h = ~~(230 * ((w - (offset * 2)) / img.width));
        glitchInterval = setInterval(function() {
            clear();
            context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, 230, offset, 0, w - (offset * 2), h);
            setTimeout(glitchImg, randInt(250,1000));
        }, 500);
    };

    var clear = function() {
        context.rect(0, 0, w, h);
        context.fillStyle = "white";
        context.fill();
    };

    var glitchImg = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < randInt(1, 13); i++) {
            var x = Math.random() * w;
            var y = Math.random() * h;
            var spliceWidth = w - x;
            var spliceHeight = randInt(5, h / 3);
            context.drawImage(canvas, 0, y, spliceWidth, spliceHeight, x, y, spliceWidth, spliceHeight);
            context.drawImage(canvas, spliceWidth, y, x, spliceHeight, 0, y, x, spliceHeight);
        }
    };

    var randInt = function(a, b) {
        return ~~(Math.random() * (b - a) + a);
    };
}
```

In this code, there has to be a way to make the pauses longer. That means keep everything as is now, but glitch ... wait longer with the image with no effect (static) .... and then glitch again after like 6 seconds (now it is somewhere between 1 and 1,5s I think).

I just need a name of the library function or something that could help me do that. I looked into setTimeout and setInterval but couldn't really figure it out. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the effect needed, I had to rewrite the init() function and also add a redraw() function like this:

```
var init = function() {
    clearInterval(glitchInterval);
    canvas.width = w = window.innerWidth;
    offset = w * 0.1;
    canvas.height = h = ~~(230 * ((w - (offset * 2)) / img.width));
    glitchInterval = setInterval(function() {
        clear();
        console.log('glitching');
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, 230, offset, 0, w - (offset * 2), h);
        glitchImg();
        setTimeout(function() {
            clear();
            redraw();
            console.log('redrawing');
        }, randInt(100,1000)); // the time the image is glitched
    }, randInt(5000,10000)); // the interval between each glitch
};
```

The redraw function:

```
function redraw() {
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, 230, offset, 0, w - (offset * 2), h);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout takes two arguments: a function to call, and a duration in milliseconds, of when to call the function. In your code there are two setTimeouts:

```
glitchInterval = setInterval(function() {
    clear();
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, 230, offset, 0, w - (offset * 2), h);
    setTimeout(glitchImg, randInt(250,1000));
}, 500);
```

glitchInterval has a duration of 500, which is 0.5 seconds. The setInterval inside of the function fired by the glitchInterval has a duration of `randInt(250, 1000)`, which is probably a random duration between 0.25 and 1 seconds. You can change these durations to achieve the desired result.

Comment: I did that, but that only changes the time the glitch is "glitched". Not the duration between each glitch.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. The time between each glitch is the duration between each glitch. It's the same thing. Could you please clarify the difference between 'the time the glitch is "glitched"' and 'duration between each glitch.'?

Comment: 1. The time the image is glitched (how long does it stay in the offset position), 2. The time between each glitch. Two different things.

Comment: Ok I understand now, I updated my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: I think you underestimated my question. I'm not a beginner and I do not struggle in editing two obvious places where the durations could be derived from. The problem is, that when I edit the setInterval, the image stays glitched for the time set. That means the interval between each individual glitch is fine now, but the image stays glitched. I think that is caused by the internal setTimeout, which is overruled by setInterval and waits for it to pass first.

Comment: I think a problem arises in conveying your question. Perhaps writing some step-by-step pseudo-code could help fix the problem and help anyone trying to help you.